# Using dplyr::mutate between two dataframes to create column based on date range

Tags: r, dplyr

Right now I have two dataframes. One contains over 11 million rows of a start date, end date, and other variables. The second dataframe contains daily values for heating degree days (basically a temperature measure).

```
set.seed(1)    
library(lubridate)
date.range <- ymd(paste(2008,3,1:31,sep="-"))
daily <- data.frame(date=date.range,value=runif(31,min=0,max=45))
intervals <- data.frame(start=daily$date[1:5],end=daily$date[c(6,9,15,24,31)])
```

In reality my daily dataframe has every day for 9 years and my intervals dataframe has entries that span over arbitrary dates in this time period.  What I wanted to do was to add a column to my `intervals` dataframe called `nhdd` that summed over the values in daily corresponding to that time interval (end exclusive).

For example, in this case the first entry of this new column would be

```
sum(daily$value[1:5])
```

and the second would be

```
sum(daily$value[2:8]) and so on.
```

I tried using the following code

```
intervals <- mutate(intervals,nhdd=sum(filter(daily,date>=start&date<end)$value))
```

This is not working and I think it might have something to do with not referencing the columns correctly but I'm not sure where to go.

I'd really like to use `dplyr` to solve this and not a loop because 11 million rows will take long enough using dplyr.  I tried using more of `lubridate` but dplyr doesn't seem to support the Period class.

Edit: I'm actually using dates from `as.Date` now instead of `lubridate`but the basic question of how to refer to a different dataframe from within `mutate` still stands

Comment: wouldn't your first entry of this new column be `sum(daily$value[1:6])` and for the second row of the new column `sum(daily$value[2:9])`?

Comment: It could go either way but one of my variables is an id and there is another row somewhere in the dataframe that has the same id and has a start date that is the same as the previous end date so I made the end exclusive to avoid double counting.

Answer (score 4):

```
eps <- .Machine$double.eps
library(dplyr)
intervals %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(nhdd = sum(daily$value[between(daily$date, start, end - eps )]))
#       start        end     nhdd
#1 2008-03-01 2008-03-06 144.8444
#2 2008-03-02 2008-03-09 233.4530
#3 2008-03-03 2008-03-15 319.5452
#4 2008-03-04 2008-03-24 531.7620
#5 2008-03-05 2008-03-31 614.2481
```

In case if you find `dplyr` solution bit slow (basically due to`rowwise`), you might want to use `data.table` for pure speed

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(intervals), start, end)
setDT(daily)[, date1 := date]
foverlaps(daily, by.x = c("date", "date1"), intervals)[, sum(value), by=c("start", "end")]
#        start        end       V1
#1: 2008-03-01 2008-03-06 144.8444
#2: 2008-03-02 2008-03-09 233.4530
#3: 2008-03-03 2008-03-15 319.5452
#4: 2008-03-04 2008-03-24 531.7620
#5: 2008-03-05 2008-03-31 614.2481
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the simplicity and just for completion and to make it a little easier I think you can replace `between(daily$date, start, end - eps)` with `between(daily$date, start, end - 1)` just so the last day isn't included (which it was for my code, even with the eps in place)