# dplyr::mutate with multiple conditions on different columns from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

***EDIT***
I leave the question in case it is helpful for someone, but it seems it was actually a problem of `dplyr` version [See below].

---

In `R` and using `dplyr`, I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)
df1 = data.frame(letter=rep(letters[1:2], each=5), min=runif(10))
df1 = mutate(df1, max=min+runif(10))
df2 = data.frame(letters=rep(letters[1:2], 25), position=runif(50), val=rnorm(50))
```

For each row of `df1`, I want to compute the sum of all `df2$val` where `df2$position` is between `df1$min` and `df1$max` AND `df2$letters` equals `df1$letter`.

From [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373160/using-dplyrmutate-between-two-dataframes-to-create-column-based-on-date-range), I can do the first part of the conditioning (i.e., `df2$position` between `df1$min` and `df1$max`):

```
incompleteCond = df1 %>% rowwise %>% 
  mutate(sumval = sum( df2$val[between(df2$position, min, max)] ))
```

But this is summing the rows of `df2` satisfying this condition without ensuring that `df2$letters` agrees with the corresponding `df1$letter`. How can I add this condition on this other column?
The following attempts do not work:

```
# Note: these solutions actually DO the job with dplyr_0.4.3!
wrong1 = df1 %>% rowwise %>% 
  mutate(sumval = 
           sum( df2$val[between(df2$position, min, max) & df2$letters==letter] ))

wrong3 = df1 %>% rowwise %>% 
  mutate(sumval = 
           sum( df2[(df2$position>=min) & (df2$position<=max) & (df2$letters==letter),
                    'val'] ))
```

---

***EDIT***

It looks like this was actually a problem of version: going from `dplyr_0.4.1` to `dplyr_0.4.3` solved the problem, meaning that both `wrong1` and `wrong3` above were actually correct (they were giving only zeros with version `0.4.1`...)

*As a side note, I haven't found a `dplyr`-only solution to subset (`filter`) `df2`, but the above works, and so does the nice answer by @r2evans.*

Comment: Why not just join the two datasets first?

Comment: Why the down votes? No reproducible data? There are. No research effort? I really did. Duplicate? Please link. Stupid question? I have been indeed stupidly blocked for some time and needed a solution quickly - is this a wrong usage of SO?! A few words of explanation for down votes would be welcome and make it at least somehow constructive.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. Because I wasn't familiar with this and so was not really aware of how to do it. Thanks for the suggestion, and thanks r2evans for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, I think:

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(sumval = sum( df2$val[df2$letters == letter & between(df2$position, min, max)] ))
## Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
## Groups: <by row>
##    letter       min       max     sumval
##    (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)
## 1       a 0.1848823 0.7375563 -3.8432366
## 2       a 0.7023740 0.9412688 -0.9138266
## 3       a 0.5733263 1.3338396  4.1341039
## 4       a 0.1680519 0.3488720 -2.5142686
## 5       a 0.9438393 1.3491215  3.6405305
## 6       b 0.9434750 1.7970234 -0.1416608
## 7       b 0.1291590 1.1055575 -5.2083130
## 8       b 0.8334488 1.0592743  1.0618699
## 9       b 0.4680185 0.9128277 -2.3595283
## 10      b 0.5499837 0.6249632  0.0000000
```

Another option, as @aosmith suggested, is to join the two datasets first.

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(grp = 1:n()) %>%
    left_join(df2, by=c('letter'='letters')) %>%
    filter(position >= min & position <= max) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarize(letter=letter[1], min=min[1], max=max[1], sumval=sum(val)) %>%
    select(-grp)
## Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
##   letter       min       max     sumval
##   (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)
## 1      a 0.1848823 0.7375563 -3.8432366
## 2      a 0.7023740 0.9412688 -0.9138266
## 3      a 0.5733263 1.3338396  4.1341039
## 4      a 0.1680519 0.3488720 -2.5142686
## 5      a 0.9438393 1.3491215  3.6405305
## 6      b 0.9434750 1.7970234 -0.1416608
## 7      b 0.1291590 1.1055575 -5.2083130
## 8      b 0.8334488 1.0592743  1.0618699
## 9      b 0.4680185 0.9128277 -2.3595283
```

One difference you may notice is that the last "b" group is not included in this latter group since none of the data is within the given range.

**Edit**: I changed the join code from using `between` (which does not vectorize the min/max arguments) to a simpler vector comparison, negating the performance-punishment of using `rowwise`. I also removed `ungroup` since, after `summarize`, the grouping is removed anyway.

FYI:

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## other attached packages:
## [1] dplyr_0.4.3
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] compiler_3.2.2  lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.1       
##  [5] assertthat_0.1  parallel_3.2.2  tools_3.2.2     DBI_0.3.1      
##  [9] htmltools_0.2.6 Rcpp_0.12.1     rmarkdown_0.8.1 digest_0.6.8
```

Comment: I did a quick `microbenchmark` on this and larger datasets (DOSed myself, in fact), and for smaller sets it looks like the `rowwise` method is marginally faster; for larger datasets, however, the `join` method is faster, on the order of 40% reduction in time. Not that benchmarks are everything, but if you have a *lot* of data, perhaps the second more verbose code would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Solution 2 working fine, but very strangely solution 1 gives me a `sumval` column only with zeros...?! This was also happening when I was searching for the solution on my original dataset... Which version of `dplyr` are you using? [Note: for solution 1, line 3 is `df2$letters` (missing 's'), is it right?]

Comment: Actually, @r2evans, how does your solution 1 differ from my `wrong1`? Checking this, `wrong1` also gives me only zeros, just as your solution 1 (and they indeed look identical to me, beyond the order of the condition). Hence both seem to be OK, the question now is to understand why it would behave so for me... ?! Any idea/suggestion? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I copy the data code from your question and my solution 1, and I do not get a column of zeroes. (The mistake in my solution 1 was "caught" because the data.frame column matching does partial-matches, do `df2$lett` also works. I'll fix it in the answer for clarity, though it doesn't change the results.) I've included my session info.

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans. May I ask you if my `wrong1` gives the same results as your solution 1 for you? Still a mystery why it doesn't work for me. To be investigated further... in any case, I was happy to learn your solution 2 which is great too!

Comment: Sorry, @ztl, when I wrote "you were close", I was in the middle of playing with a couple of different ways of coding it, and ended up on the same code you had in `wrong1`. In my haste, I didn't realize my working code was the same as your "seemingly-not-working" code. Your `wrong1` code does not produce all zeroes, so perhaps it's something else you have there. I recommend you look at package versions and start with a completely fresh *R* environment and re-run your code (if you haven't already tried that). My apologies for missing the point on that.

Comment: Don't apologize @r2evans! ;-) And thanks for the help. Incredible, it looks like it was indeed a problem of `dplyr` version, updating from `0.4.1` to `0.4.3` (like you) solved the problem, ´wrong1` and your solution work both fine for me now (and yes, I tried many times to restard a fresh *R* environment before). This is really confusing to me!