# R - subset and find max value in df2 by date range in df1 based on ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been looking online for hours, and haven't found a similar problem, so here goes:

I've got two data frames : `formedmeterdata`, and `fbills`. `fbills` includes a date range for service (`Service.Begin.Date`, and `Service.End.Date`, and the max kW for each service period by `Location`. `formedmeterdata` has `Meter.Peak.kW` for each `Location`.

I was thinking `join()` function in `dplyr`, but that wouldn't subset through dates in `formedmeterdata` or give me the max `Meter.Peak.kw` for the month from daily readings, I don't think.

I'm trying to combine the data frames so that I get something like:

```
Location  Service.Start.Date  Service.End.Date   Billed.kW   MaxMonthlybyDayMeterkW
1000      09/27/2016         11/01/2016              192       185
```

`formedmeterdata` looks like:

```
Site      Meter.Peak.kW   Date
1 10000        150   2016-01-10
2 10000        143   2016-01-11
3 10000        155   2016-01-12
4 10022        154   2016-03-22
5 10022        122   2016-03-23
6 10022        143   2016-03-24
```

`fbills` looks like:

```
Location..  Service.Begin.Date    Service.End.Date       monthly_peak
       <int>             <date>           <date>        <dbl>
1      10000         2014-12-27       2015-01-28          120
2      10000         2015-01-29       2015-02-26          130
3      10000         2015-02-27       2015-03-27          140
4      10020         2015-03-28       2015-04-28          147
```

My current code is:

```
> fbills %>%
+     rowwise() %>%
+     mutate(Metermaxes=max(formedmeterdata$Meter.Peak.kW[between(fbills$Service.Begin.Date,fbills$Service.End.Date)]))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "right" is missing, with no default.
>
```

Comment: It's hard to attempt at this because the ideal output doesn't seem to be explained by the rows of your sample data.  My advice would be look into `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarise()`.  Maybe combined with the `lubridate` package if you need to group by month and year.

Comment: @Balter I was thinking that, but pretty much I'd need to look find the max of formedmeterdata (which is daily) according to the service periods prescribed by fbills. fbills also has 200 stores, so I'd need a way to filter for that too.

Comment: I think I understand more.  If you don't care about speed you can write a loop that will loop through each row of `fbills`, and then subset `formedmeterdata` like this: `for(i in 1:nrow(fbills)){ row <- fbills[i,] sub <- subset(formedmeterdata, subset = Site == row$Location & Date >= row$Service.Begin.Date & Date <= row$Service.End.Date) }`.  And then do what you want from there to build a new dataframe with the info you want.

Comment: Or if it you need to analyze each location block in `fbills` use `for(i in unique(fbills$Location))` to subset each block in fbills.

Comment: hmmm probably going to try to stick with dplyr or a similar package for the time being because I am subsetting by service.begin.date, service.end.date and store ID - I thinkthat could get very messy with a loop.

Comment: Ah well :)  Usually in this cases for me it's a one and done analysis where I don't care about speed.  I would recommend adding data that can support your final desired output though and you're more likely to receive help. Unless it does and I'm just missing it.

Comment: You got your current code form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373160/using-dplyrmutate-between-two-dataframes-to-create-column-based-on-date-range). So there you can see that `between` takes three variables. That's the error that you get right now. It won't resolve the issue but at least takes one bug down.